# How do I make this table responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

This is a table with inline styles. It is not ideal for responsive, so I need to find another way to make the table. I want it to look like this when the screen is full size, approximately 1140px and up. It doesn't need to be a table, and I am open to anything. Maybe DIVs with media queries would be best.

It is a login page and when it shrinks I want the buttons and image to enlarge and take up more of the space. The buttons and image will have to be on top of one another  when sized down I understand that. The hope is to keep the layout similar when it is full sized to the one here:

```
<table style="width:100%;height:80%;margin-top:10px">
        <tbody><tr>

    <td style="padding-top:10px;text-align:right;" >
        <button style="border-radius:15px; font-size:22px;color:#e7e7e7;width:150px;height:50px;background-color:orange;box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #CCC;" class="btn-help" onclick="gotoHelp()">Help <img src="img/help6.png" style=""> </button>
    </td>

            <td style="text-align:center">
                <img title="PIV/CAC Login" src="img/piv-image.jpg" style=" cursor:pointer;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain;font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;width:180px" onclick="window.location.assign(&#39;tabbed.jsp&#39;)">
            </td>
        <td style="padding-top:10px;text-align:left">
            <button type="button" style="border-radius:15px; font-size:22px;color:#e7e7e7; width:150px;height:50px;  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #CCC;" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.assign(&#39;tabbed.jsp&#39;)"> Login <img src="img/login4.png" style=""></button>
    </td>

    </tr>


    </tbody></table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/b3qxu3c3/

Comment: As this is not tabular data, using a `<table>` is strongly discouraged. You can use `div`s to achieve what you want. Please provide a JSFiddle or CodePen with the divs and CSS separated as a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this lines to your css

```
table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
        text-align: center !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="table_main">
<table style="width:100%;height:80%;margin-top:10px">
        <tbody><tr>

    <td style="padding-top:10px;text-align:right;" >
        <button style="border-radius:15px; font-size:22px;color:#e7e7e7;width:150px;height:50px;background-color:orange;box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #CCC;" class="btn-help" onclick="gotoHelp()">Help <img src="img/help6.png" style=""> </button>
    </td>

            <td style="text-align:center">
                <img title="PIV/CAC Login" src="img/piv-image.jpg" style=" cursor:pointer;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain;font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;width:180px" onclick="window.location.assign(&#39;tabbed.jsp&#39;)">
            </td>
        <td style="padding-top:10px;text-align:left">
            <button type="button" style="border-radius:15px; font-size:22px;color:#e7e7e7; width:150px;height:50px;  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #CCC;" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.assign(&#39;tabbed.jsp&#39;)"> Login <img src="img/login4.png" style=""></button>
    </td>

    </tr>


    </tbody></table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table_main{
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
.table_main table{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: *As this is not tabular data, using a <table> is strongly discouraged.*  « This should be your first flag.

Comment: It improved it @Gaurav, but how do I get it from not scrolling left to right when sized down? The buttons and image just on top of one another when the page is sized down?

Comment: that will be just different from this method..read this documentation https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't use the `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, but instead I use `<div>` tags with classes and define these as table components in the CSS, like

```
.my_container {
  display: table;
}
.my_rows {
  display: table-row;
}
.my_cells {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

This has a lot of advantages, one of them also to be able to use completely different `display` parameters in media queries for smaller screens. For example I can simply place all former table-cells below each other (vertically) on a small smartphone screen instead of horizontal placement by using `display: block` in the media query.

Other advantages of the use of table-properties are

- the ability to center their content horizontally *and* vertically,
- the possibility of their automatic distribution across a given width
  while taking in account their content
- achieving the same vertical height for all "columns" including their backgrounds without the need for any other methods.